What happens if you lose "half your life" if you have less than zero life?
I was looking at the card Unstoppable Slasher (which has "If this deals combat damage to a player, that player loses half their life, rounded up").
What would happen if, say, an opponent dealt damage by Unstoppable Slasher already had -7 life ( but still alivethanks to a Platinum Angel)?  Would the player gain 4 life?

This question is similar to: How does doubling of life work when you are at negative life?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Doubling negative life does work differently than losing negative life. My answer explains the difference.

@murgatroid99 true, but the answer from the proposed duplicate cites the same rule and highlights the part that would be used to reason about that difference. In the SE model as I understand it, this is a reason to broaden the wording of the original question so that it can serve as a proper duplicate (perhaps something like "how do life gain and loss effects work...").

It's still a different question, with a different answer. The fact that the answers to the two questions are in the same place does not make them duplicates.

@KarlKnechtel I don't think that's true, about broadening the original question. In fact, I'd say it's more consistent with the SE model that you don't fundamentally change questions or answers after they're posted. Fixing typos, clarifying wording, that sort of thing is fine, but not broadening a question's scope. (Occasionally exceptions can be made if the question was kind of bad originally, can be improved a lot by a major edit, and the edit doesn't render any existing answer invalid.)

The player loses 0 life, so they still have -7 life.
Rule 107.1b says

Most of the time, the Magic game uses only positive numbers and zero. You can't choose a negative number, deal negative damage, gain negative life, and so on. However, it's possible for a game value, such as a creature's power, to be less than zero. If a calculation or comparison needs to use a negative value, it does so. If a calculation that would determine the result of an effect yields a negative number, zero is used instead, unless that effect doubles or sets to a specific value a player's life total or the power and/or toughness of a creature or creature card.

In this case, the player has -7 life, so half their life rounded up is -3. That is the result of the calculation to determine how much life the player loses. Since that number is negative, 0 is used instead, so the player loses 0 life, remaining at -7.

remains the question whether halving a negative amount of life would mean getting to -10 from -7 or to -3. My gut feeling tells me you should get to -10. End result is still 0 but this is potentially important if a healing effect is also applied during the same calculation.

The answer is that you go to -7. That is the conclusion that applying the rules results in. I don't understand the distinction you're trying to make where some other answer would need to be considered, but if you can point to a card or interaction where that would be relevant I can address that.

As I said, it might make a difference if some healing effect or something else that would increase the health to over 0 depending on actual value was in effect. Edge case certainly. Not sure what that would be, but say you have an effect that adds 4 life, you're at -7 and now a card is played that changes that to -3. End result would be +1 and you survive. If that card instead either keeps you at -7 or worse puts you at -10 you die.

If the player had -3 life instead of -7, the effect in question would still cause them to lose 0 life, leaving their life total unchanged. That is true for any negative life total because the rule in question is independent of the specific value. The fact that some other effect could change the life total to a different negative value before the effect in question resolves is immaterial to that conclusion.

@jwenting: due to that potential ambiguity, any card that overrode the general rule of clamping effect damage to a minimum of zero would hopefully be worded in a way that makes it clear what exactly it does for that case.
